# Querying DHCP server for fetching particular option (using option ID)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, client-server, dhcp

How can we query DHCP server to fetch option Data (set on DHCP server) using option ID or any other means?

Platform: windows
Language: C#

Comment: There are quite a lot of tutorials on Google about this. What have you tried?

Comment: Calling "DhcpGetOptionInfo()" always return 5 (means failure)